# syscall.LoadDLL() fails on all computers except one; what do I do?

Tags: winapi, go

When I call `syscall.LoadDLL("my.dll")` in my notebook, it works well.

But when I copy the execution file (.exe) and `my.dll` to other computers, it will fail and show the following error:

```
Failed to load my.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

The my.dll could be found in the same directory.

I don't know what happened.

Comment: If you fetch the files "over the Internet" (which includes unpacking them form a ZIP archive downloaded by a browser) you first need to remove it.
I mean [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/image10.png). Is it the problem?

Comment: Thx！I solve it. I found that the "my.dll" has some dependency dlls. After I installed lack of dlls, it works well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .DLL probably depends on some other .DLL not installed on these other systems. [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) is a useful tool to debug these types of issues...